# SMS verification from application for android

Tags: android, smsmanager

I have developed an application where I want to do sms verification of the user who is using the application from the same number from which he is registering. Right now I have released the application only for India. I need to know whether I need to put country code if I want to go for other countries. Like right now am able to send sms from users phone without country code. So do I really need country code to send the sms from the phone.
I have used following code to send the sms.

```
 SmsManager sms = SmsManager.getDefault();
        String smsTxt = "Please enter " + string
                + " into Myapp for verification.";
        sms.sendTextMessage(phno2, null, smsTxt, null, null);
```

For the above code I haven't put any country code. Do i really need the country code.

Comment: if your requirement is only specific to india then +91 is ISO COUNTRY CODE for india  then why do you need country code for sending sms you can do it via statically also but if you want to go for all countries then you must use country code and its comuplsion else you will get lots of issue in future

Comment: But currently am not storing the numbers of user with the country code. So if I start using country code in database then I have to change lots of logic. Is it ok if I send sms using the country code but store the number in database without the country code

Comment: yes its ok no worry but design architecture of database or coding in a such way that it will not effect in future requirement if it is limited to india only then its ok but  for all country you need country code